Installing Deno error: JSR package manifest for '@deno/installer-shell-setup' failed to load
I would like to install Deno with the following command:
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/install.sh | sh

After extracting the binary, I got the following error:
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /home/<user>/.deno/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: /home/<user>/.deno/bin/deno  
Deno was installed successfully to /home/<user>/.deno/bin/deno
error: JSR package manifest for '@deno/installer-shell-setup' failed to load. Import 'https://jsr.io/@deno/installer-shell-setup/meta.json' failed: error sending request for url (https://jsr.io/@deno/installer-shell-setup/meta.json): client error (Connect): invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer

Unfortunately, the @deno/installer-shell-setup package can not be loaded because of certification error. It is highly probable because I connected to corporate network.
Is it possible to continue the installer setup?

In this case, since the deno binary was successfully downloaded, you might  be able to complete running the installer by manually running the next step manually and adding the --unsafely-ignore-certificate-errors flag to ignore this error, like this:
$ "$HOME/.deno/bin/deno" run --unsafely-ignore-certificate-errors -A --reload jsr:@deno/installer-shell-setup/bundled "$HOME/.deno"

This should complete the installation by configuring your shell's PATH and completions.

More generally, it's not necessary to use the installer to install Deno; it's just for convenience.
As described in the Installation section of the documentation, Deno is distributed as a single binary. You can download the latest binary for your platform from their Releases page on GitHub (or you can build it from source if you really want to: it will be slow, but it should work without much hassle if you have Rust/Cargo installed).
For example, on Mac OS, I download it with wget, unzip it with unzip,  and then I can run the deno binary:
$ wget https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.46.3/deno-x86_64-apple-darwin.zip
...
2024-10-02 15:43:34 (47.8 MB/s) - ‘deno-x86_64-apple-darwin.zip’ saved [43844272/43844272]

$ unzip deno-x86_64-apple-darwin.zip 
Archive:  deno-x86_64-apple-darwin.zip
  inflating: deno

$ ./deno --version
deno 1.46.3 (stable, release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 12.9.202.5-rusty
typescript 5.5.2

The installer script would move the binary to ~/.deno/bin, then prompt you to modify your shell configuration (.bash_profile or similar) to add that directory to your PATH. You can do that yourself:
$ mkdir -p ~/.deno/bin

$ mv ./deno ~/.deno/bin/deno

$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.deno/bin/deno"' >> ~/.bash_profile

The installer supports shells other than Bash, and can set up completion for Deno subcommands. If you need that, you'll need to dig a bit deeper than what I've describe here.

Previously, I installed Deno by building from source using Cargo. However, I got some error because Deno (from the .cargo/bin dir) couldn't download JSR package. That's why I came back to the original installation.

Can you elaborate on why the /bundled path needs to be appended at the end of the JSR package?

@PéterSzilvási Good question. That's what the install.sh script in the deno_install repository did, so I copied that and tested it locally and it seemed to work, so I stuck with what they did, even though it seemed unnecessary. But looking into it now, it seems like this is a recent change and this GitHub thread gives us the reason: if you don't use the bundled version it needs to pull in some dependencies and that seemed wasteful for an install script. But it should work either way.
